# Solving for $Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been breaking my head over this matrix. This is part of a solution for mechanical vibrations and it's been a while since I've done linear algebra, but it shouldn't be this hard.
I just grab the $A$ matrix and row reduce it to echelon form on my TI 84 (and even MATLAB). However my answers don't seem to match. I already scoured the internet and my LA book with no avail.

Any ideas?
[image: natural frequency mode]

Comment: ...What's the problem?

Comment: I don't know what the bit about $\omega_2$ means. You are trying to solve $Ax=0$. Usually, such a system will have only one solution, namely, $x=0$. The exception comes if $A$ has determinant zero, but when matrix entries are floating point approximations, you really can't tell whether a determinant is zero. When it is, you get not just one solution, but an infinity of solutions, all scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: @Gerry: They needn't all be scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: @Cam, in general, no, but this matrix clearly has nullity at most $1$.

Comment: @Ortix92: Can you post the original matrix, state that omega is an eigenvalue and you are looking for the eigenvectors? This would be helpful to give a more concise answer. Regards

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys. Forget about the omega. It's just a value that is plugged into the original matrix containing variables. This matrix corresponds to the value omega_2 (I don't know LaTeX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers need not be identical. It suffices that one be a scalar multiple of the other. What you seem to be doing here is finding an eigenvector associated to a particular eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix. Eigenvectors associated to particular eigenvalues need not be unique (indeed, there may be linearly independent eigenvectors associated to the same eigenvalue).

Comment: I misread the problem. I had to find the eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

You have a [homogeneous system of linear equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular%5Fvalue%5Fdecomposition#Solving%5Fhomogeneous%5Flinear%5Fequations), i.e., the right hand side is equal to the zero vector. As pointed out by @GerryMyerson, such a system has a non-trivial (non-zero) solution when the determinant of $A$ is zero. You pasted in the the rounded off floating-point values, but even with these one can observe that your determinant is about $-7.1477 \times 10^{-4}$, on the order of the precision of the values you provided.

To solve such a system in Matlab you would use the [`null`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html) function: `null(A)`. This will work if you don't round any of your values. Otherwise you'll need to resort to calculating all of the singular values via [`svd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html): `[U,S,V] = svd(A);` `x = V(:,end)`. The vector will be approximately equal to your expected solution normalized: `[1;0.5275;-1.2638]/norm([1;0.5275;-1.2638]);`. You'll see that `A*x` will only be equal to zero within the tolerance of your rounding. The `eig` function can be used also to obtain the appropriate eigenvector, but `svd` conveniently returns the singular values in decreasing order.